# How to Dynamically Set Zingchart Attribute within Angular ng-Repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zingchart

Using AngularJS, I'm trying to build a page which features a different dynamically generated Zingchart for each object in an array. My problem is that -- as the data and variable names are dynamically generated in my controller on page load -- I'm not sure how to properly reference them within the Zingchart directives.

In my controller, here is how the variables are dynamically generated:

```
function getWeeklyNflLines(){
  oddsService.getWeeklyNflLines($stateParams.weekNumb).then(function(games){
    vm.nflLines = games;
    for (i=0; i<vm.nflLines.length; i++){
      $scope[vm.nflLines[i].AwayAbbrev] = { [Zingchart json configuration goes here] }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in my view where I try and produce the Zingchart, I've got:

```
<div ng-repeat="game in vm.nflLines>
  <div zingchart zc-json="{{game.AwayAbbrev}}" zc-width="100%" zc-height="350px"></div>
</div>
```

So to review: I set the 'AwayAbbrev' $scope variable in the controller -- which should correspond to 'game.AwayAbbrev' within my ng-repeat -- but when I try to do this, I get the following error in my browser:

`angular.js:13550 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{game.AwayAbbrev}}] starting at [{game.AwayAbbrev}}].`

I tried changing the zc-json attribute to ng-attr-zc-json to try and interpolate it, but that didn't work.

Any idea how I might accomplish this? Thanks in advance for any help!

====

EDIT: I should have mentioned that I also tried removing the curly braces altogether (e.g, zc-json="game.AwayAbbrev"), and though this took care of the error it returned no data.

===

EDIT #2: Please see Tjaart's answer below as this solved my problem. I will note there was one additional error in my code unrelated to my original question; I needed to include an id as a Zingchart attribute, which I incremented within my ng-repeat by index. So the final piece of code looked like this:

```
<div zingchart id="pick-chart[{{$index}}]" zc-json="nflLines[game.AwayAbbrev]" zc-width="100%" zc-height="350px"></div>
```

Comment: are you trying to pass the `game.AwayAbbrev` variable as `json`?

Comment: I am indeed, as that's the format required by the Zingchart directive explained here: https://www.zingchart.com/docs/developers/angularjs-charts/. For what it's worth, when I explicitly change the variable name in my view to one of the 'AwayAbbrevs' that are dynamically generated in the Controller, the chart displays as intended, so the format in which the data is being passed doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: Please see my answer, I think what you trying to achieve is access the values by using the `["PropertyName"]` notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating the `json` objects directly on `$scope` you can try do add them on a separate property:

```
$scope.nfLines = {};

function getWeeklyNflLines(){
  oddsService.getWeeklyNflLines($stateParams.weekNumb).then(function(games){
    vm.nflLines = games;
    for (i=0; i<vm.nflLines.length; i++){
      $scope.nfLines[vm.nflLines[i].AwayAbbrev] = { [Zingchart json configuration goes here] }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can update your HTML to the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="game in vm.nflLines>
  <div zingchart zc-json="nfLines[game.AwayAbbrev]" zc-width="100%" zc-height="350px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This nailed it. Thank you! Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

my be you just need to use it without The double curly brace, like this

```
<div ng-repeat="game in vm.nflLines>
  <div zingchart zc-json="game.AwayAbbrev" zc-width="100%" zc-height="350px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - I should have mentioned that I tried this as well, and though it got rid of the browser error caused by the curly braces, it returned nothing/blank data within my view.

Answer (score 0):

#### The variables using zing chart dynamically generated

```html
<div ng-if="chart_names.length" ng-repeat="chartName in chart_names">
    <div id="{{ chartName }}"></div>
</div>
```

```js
$scope.chart_names = [];

$scope.zcJson = {
    type: "line",
    series: [
        {values: [20, 40, 25, 50, 15, 45, 33, 34]}
    ],
    "scale-x": {
        labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug"]
    },
};
```

**Function to initialize ZingCharts**

```js
$scope.initZingCharts = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.chart_names.length; i++) {
        var chartName = $scope.chart_names[i];
        zingchart.render({
            id: chartName,
            data: $scope[chartName],
            height: '400px',
            width: '100%'
        });
    }
};
```

**Fetch data dynamically using API**

```js
$scope.loadCharts = function() {
    chartService.get_chart($scope.add).then(function (res) {
        // inside forloop prepare multiple zing chart and chart_names data 
        // like this $scope.zcJson_1 = angular.copy(zcJson);

        // Call the initialization function after the data is loaded
        $scope.initZingCharts();
    });
  };
```